# MISRA C2012:10.8 violation in the sample code

Tags: c, misra

```
typedef struct{
    sint16 temperature;
    uint32 Setdata;
} VariableA;

VariableA TableData[N];

static uint16 linearinterpolation(const currentdata *pcurData,const VariableA* pTableData)
{   /* Declare local variables */
    sint32 deltaOut;
    sint32 deltaIn;
    uint16 output;
    uint16 idx;
    /* DeltaIn of  temperatures. */
    deltaIn = (sint32)(pTableData[idx].temperature) - (sint32)(pTableData[idx-1].temperature);
    /* DeltaOut of  Setdata */
    deltaOut = (sint32)pTableData[idx].Setdata - (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].Setdata;
    /* Division by 0 protection. */
    if (deltaOut == 0)
    {   /* if the division == 0 */
            output = pTableData[idx-1].Setdata;
    }
    else
    {   /*MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.8 */ 
        output =(uint16)((( deltaOut / deltaIn) *((sint32)(pcurData->temperature) - (sint32)(pTableData[idx-1].temperature))) + (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].Setdata );
    }
    return output; 
}
```

I have no idea to solve  10.8, does someone can explain and fix it, thank you very much.

---

MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.8
The value of a composite expression shall not be cast to a different essential type category or a wider essential type
Description
Rule Definition
The value of a composite expression shall not be cast to a different essential type category or a wider essential type.

Comment: What are the errors for those of use that don't happen to have misra memorized?

Comment: Seems to me these might just go away if you make `output` a `uint16` to match the function return type.

Comment: when i change the define type output as a uint16,

Comment: the 10.8 warning still have .

Comment: I am guessing that the clue is in the words "composite expression". Try assigning the result of that expression to a variable of type sint32, (`your_sint32_variable`) and then in a separate statement assign `output = (uint16)your_sint32_variable;`

Comment: Split very long expressions into several and use temporary variables. Also drop home-made integer types and always use `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this line of code:

```
output = (uint16)(((deltaOut / deltaIn) * ((sint32)(pcurData->temperature) - (sint32)(pTableData[idx-1].temperature))) + (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].Setdata);
```

- MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.8 states that you should not cast the value of a composite expression to a different essential type category or a wider essential type: the composite expression is the whole interpolation expression and the different essential type is `uint16`, which is probably a typedef on `unsigned short`. You could use an intermediary variable `output32` to store the `sint32` result and cast that as `output = (uint16)output32;`.
- Yet this MISRA warning is hiding a much more important problem: the scale operation should be computed as `A * B / C` with a type large enough to handle `A * B`, not `(A / C) * B` using integer arithmetics where rouding will reduce the precision.

If `deltaOut`is known to be in the range of `sint16`, you could write:

```
sint32 deltaTemp = (sint32)pcurData->temperature - (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].temperature;
sint32 adjust32 = deltaOut * deltaTemp / deltaIn;
sint32 output32 = pTableData[idx-1].Setdata + adjust32;
output = (uint16)output32;
```

Otherwise, you might need 64-bit arithmetics:

```
sint32 deltaTemp = (sint32)pcurData->temperature - (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].temperature;
sint64 adjust64 = (sint64)deltaOut * (sint64)deltaTemp / (sint64)deltaIn;
sint32 output32 = pTableData[idx-1].Setdata + (sint32)adjust64;
output = (uint16)output32;
```

If the target has fast floating point hardware, you could compute the interpolation in floating point with `float` or `double` arithmetics:

```
sint32 deltaTemp = (sint32)pcurData->temperature - (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].temperature;
double adjust64 = (double)deltaOut * (double)deltaTemp / (double)deltaIn;
sint32 output32 = pTableData[idx-1].Setdata + (sint32)adjust64;
output = (uint16)output64;
```

As a rule of thumb, avoid long expressions, define variables for intermediary results and choose their type carefully to avoid overflow or precision loss.

Another remark: what is `idx` in your function? It seems to be a global variable. You should avoid global variables, especially with such a bland short name.

Comment: No ,  the idx, it’s the local variable for this function

Comment: @Rickykidd: `idx` is not defined inside the function as posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

MISRA C:2012 Rule 10.8 states:

> The value of a composite expression shall not be cast to a different
> essential type category or a **wider** essential type

Looking at your code:

```
output = (uint16)( ( ( deltaOut / deltaIn )
                   * ( (sint32)( pcurData->temperature) - (sint32)(pTableData[idx-1].temperature) ) )
                 + (sint32)pTableData[idx-1].Setdata );
```

Lets see...

- `output` is a `uint16`
- The right hand side is cast to `uint16`
- The right hand side is a composite expression in `sint32`

So:

```
output = (uint16)( composite expression in sint32 )
```

Yes, you are **NOT** violating the guideline R.10.8 because of width - you are casting to a **narrower** type; however you are violating by casting `signed` to `unsigned` within the composite expression.

You have three choices...

1. Deviate the rule
2. Modify so that `output` is `sint32` and do all calcs in signed
3. Are the X and M values all unsigned? Could the calculation be performed in `uint32` or `uint16`?

See profile